# SASS calculate column widths for grid

Tags: css, sass

I have written this piece of code to calculate column widths for my grid system:

```
@mixin calc-width($index, $type) {
  $column-calculation: (100% - ($gutter-width-procent * ($column-count - 1))) / $column-count;
  $column-width: ($column-calculation * $index);
  $gutter: ($gutter-width-procent * ($index - 1));
  @if ($index > 0) {
    @if ($type != 'width') {
      #{$type}: $column-width + $gutter + $gutter-width-procent;
    } @else {
      #{$type}: $column-width + $gutter;
    }
  }
}
```

I am calling that up in a different function like this:

```
  @for $index from 1 through $column-count {
    &.size-#{$index} {
      @include calc-width($index, 'width');
    }
  }
```

With the variables of:

```
$column-count: 12 !default; //12
$row-max-width: 1024;

$gutter-width-px: 15px !default; //In px
$gutter-width-procent: percentage($gutter-width-px / $row-max-width);
```

I like the system. But there is one thing that doesnt seem correct...

Can i do this line on another way, then substracting from 100%?

```
$column-calculation: (100% - ($gutter-width-procent * ($column-count - 1))) / $column-count;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure, if this solves your problem, but i wouldn't create the grid gutters like that. You can easily create them if you use "box-sizing", a negative margin on the parent and a padding for every column. So your ("pseudo")-HTML could look like:

```
.parent
    .column
    .column
    .column
```

And your CSS like that:

```
.parent {
    margin-left: -GUTTER;
}
.child {
    padding-left: GUTTER;
}
```

Your SASS function to create the widths for the columns could then be simplified as well. I made a [pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FfrJp) to show you one way to solve your gutter problem.

This SASS function is just for testing and doesn't check for duplicates (`.size1-2` (50%) and `.size2-4`) and other stuff.

Comment: I'm sorry, i totally forgot to mention that i am using the `box-sizing: border-box` and other different CSS properties wich im going to post now. But the problem when i use the padding is that i cant give the column a background color. Only the content's of it. Wich is getting very ugly when using `margins` for example on `h1`or `h2`s

Comment: @Dreiba You're right, using that method you can't set a `background-color` on `.column` directly. As you already said you just need to create a new element inside `.column` and give this element a `background-color` of your choice. I didn't understand your issue with the `margins` on headlines though. Can you give me an example? Probably I can help with that.

Comment: There is'nt really an issue with the `margins`. But i'm not really sure about how the code where it calculates all column `width`s. Where it substracts from the 100%. Its working, but its very confusing...`$column-calculation: (100% - ($gutter-width-procent * ($column-count - 1))) / $column-count;
`

Comment: @Dreiba If you have x columns, you always have (x - 1) gutters. So this piece `(100% - ($gutter-width-procent * ($column-count - 1)))` calculates the width of your row minus all the gutters (11 in your case). It then divides this value by the amount of your columns (12 in your case) to get the width of only one column. While this should work, your CSS gets a lot more complex, if you are doing it this way. So apart from the `background-color` "issue" you mentioned (which can be easily solved) I don't really see an advantage over the other method.

Comment: Ty :3, but about this `background-color` issue... I always have to create another element inside every column right?

Comment: @Dreiba For now that's the only way I'm aware of... See this updated [pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IDEto). But i personally don't think it is too bad. Using flexbox we could most likely get rid of the extra container, but unfortunately it is IE10+ only (http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox)

Comment: Thanks for the pen, i see what your doing but i dont really like to overload my page with extra `div`s. I'm sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

I may be getting the wrong end of the stick here but if if you used `box-sizing: border-box;` and padding for your gutters then you wouldn't have to do any calculation. There's a great post about border-box [here](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/).

Comment: I'm sorry. I totally forgot to mention that im already using `border-box` already. (And other css properties)